# Close kendo window from page loaded into the window

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo window which is open as iframe and loads a page.

How can I close that window from a button (or by registering a startup script) from the loaded page?

Specifically I have the kendo window as below:

```
var win = j$("<div />").kendoWindow({
        iframe: true,
        actions: ['Close'],
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: title,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        close: onClose,
        content: 'mypage.aspx',
        visible: false /*don't show it yet*/
    }).center().open();
```

How can I close this window from mypage.aspx?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends - if, for example, you have buttons inside your page, and you know the `id` beforehand, you can use the `refresh` event (which is triggered when the content has finished loading) to attach a close handler ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/Yh4h9/)):

```
var win = $("<div />").kendoWindow({
    iframe: true,
    actions: ['Close'],
    draggable: true,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: title,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    close: onClose,
    content: 'mypage.aspx',
    refresh: function () {
        var that = this;            
        var iframe = $(this.element).find("iframe");

        // find the element, e.g. a button you want to close with
        var button = $(iframe).contents().find("#my-button");
        $(button).click(function() {
            that.close();
        });
    },
    visible: true 
}).data().kendoWindow.center().open();
```

As an alternative, you could access [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.parent) from within your `iframe` to get access to the Kendo Window, or to a close function you have defined in the parent window.
Note that this will only work if the content is served from the same domain, subdomain and port (same-origin policy).